Implement change password functionality at sprint authorization server
Currently my micro-services are behind the spring cloud gateway, also act as oauth2 client for spring authorization server where my identity authentication happens.
I have implemented both usernamePassword Authentication (for business) and oauth2 social login (for individual users) with spring authorization server. My new requirement is to develop the change password functionality for usernamePassword Authentication. Initially admin will be create the account for user-pass authentication with temporary password, and he should change when logged into system. I have referred the /.well-know/change-password spec in spring security and implemented this at SAS.
When I land on the login page from SAS through SCG, I tried to changed the password of the user using forget/change password section in UI. At this point, the user is not authenticated with IDP, it is throwing following errors and returning 500 errors.
logger":"c.c.s.service.JpaUserDetailsManager     ","message":"Changing password for user anonymousUser\n"}
logger":"c.c.s.service.JpaUserDetailsManager     ","message":"No authentication manager set. Password won't be re-checked.\n"}

Here is my code
@GetMapping("/change-password")
public String getChangePasswordPage() {
    return "forgot-password";
}

@PostMapping(path = "/update-password", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> changePassword(PasswordUpdate passwordUpdate) {
    if (userDetailsManager.userExists(passwordUpdate.getUsername())) {
        if (encoder.matches(passwordUpdate.getOldPassword(), userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(passwordUpdate.getUsername()).getPassword())) {
            userDetailsManager.changePassword(passwordUpdate.getOldPassword(), passwordUpdate.getNewPassword());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Password not matched for username: " + passwordUpdate.getUsername());
        }
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Username not found in system: " + passwordUpdate.getUsername());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Password has been changed!");
}

Please provide a way to implement this at IDP if possible with code flow, thanks in advance!

Able to fix this issue by setting username inside authentication context.
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
      passwordUpdate.getUsername(), authentication.getCredentials(), authentication.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(new SecurityContextImpl(authentication));
    userDetailsManager.changePassword(passwordUpdate.getOldPassword(), passwordUpdate.getNewPassword());

